# NSString stringByAppendingString: recursive long String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

i have now since a while a systematic problem with NSStrings and appending these to another. I searched in the web, but i couldn't find something witch satisfied me.

I have a string declared like this in the header and properly syntesized in the implementation:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dataString;
```

I am refreshing every 200 ms data. I want to put this into a string (NSData would be more nice i guess) after the old one recursive. The string should grow every 200ms then.

```
 dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString:superString];


 NSLog(@"%@",dataString);
```

But my code is is breaking here!

LOG DATA:

```
2011-07-05 12:40:54.039 Acceleration[1658:307] /AccelerationApp2011-07-05_12:40.txt
2011-07-05 12:40:56.825 Acceleration[1658:307] Acceleration:
 X-axis: -0.036224 
 Y-axis: -0.036224 
 Z-axis: -0.941833 
 Global Acc: 0.9 g 
(gdb)
```

...then i get program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Is the Problem that the string may be too long?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to retain the return value from stringByAppending... or assign it to your property:

```
self.dataString = [self.dataString stringByAppendingString:superString];
```

Comment: Thanks, working! But can you literally explain what happens with my value? Basic question, i know...

Comment: It's basic memory management. Your code leaks the old object and doesn't take ownership of the new one. You should read the Memory Management Programming Guide - it's a good read. :)

Answer (score 1):

you're not retaining it. `[dataString stringByAppendingString:superString];` returns an autoreleased string.

```
[dataString autorelease];
dataString = [[dataString stringByAppendingString:superString] retain];
```